# Magento 2 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface on catalog/product pages and widgets

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product, error, fatal-error

Recently we've started experiencing issues on any pages that pull data from the catalog or individual products.

I'm not quite sure what the cause of this change was, as everything was working fine up until a couple days ago.

After enabling error logging, we are seeing the following error displayed on catalog/product pages:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface
>   Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\LowestPriceOptionsProviderInterface
>   in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:73
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(71):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Configu...')
>
> **1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php(46):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Configu...')**
>
> **2/var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox/Interceptor.php(14):
>   Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool),
>   Object(Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\Confi in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php
>   on line 73**

Comment: If you have installed plugin, find the files that inject  `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\LowestPriceOptionsProviderInterface`.

Comment: @PYYick Is there a way to track down which plugin could be triggering the error? I also saw an error in our apache log relating to braintree payments plugin within the dev/tests folder, but I'm not sure if that relates or not.

Comment: The best method is find the file(s) that use this interface in whole project. If it's not core file, try disable it and see if the error continues.